# Dynamically Declare Function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, datepicker, iteration

How can I dynamically create multiple functions of calendar() in my code?

```
function calendar(){
  new JsDatePick({
    useMode:2,
    target:'datepicker',
    dateFormat:'%m-%d-%Y',
    weekStartDay: 0
  });
```

Here's my attempt and I'm so close I can almost taste it:

> ```
> $(function() {
>     $("[id^='datepicker']").each(function() {
>         var id = parseInt(this.id.replace("datepicker", ""));
>
>         function calendar+id(){
>             new JsDatePick({
>                 useMode:2,
>                 target:'datepicker'+id,
>                 dateFormat:'%m-%d-%Y',
>                 weekStartDay: 0
>             });
>         }
>     });
> });
> ```

Comment: Is there a need for it? From what I see, you could pass the `id` to the function `calendar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a need for multiple function. You could pass `id` to the calendar function like below,

```
$(function() {
    $("[id^='datepicker']").each(function() {
        calendar(parseInt(this.id.replace("datepicker", "")));
    });
    function calendar(id){
       new JsDatePick({
         useMode:2,
         target:'datepicker'+id,
         dateFormat:'%m-%d-%Y',
         weekStartDay: 0
       });
   }
});
```

Comment: This looks like a good idea however it seems that the target: 'datepicker' + id syntax isn't valid. It would return datepickerundefined when I use onmousedown='calendar(2);'

Comment: @theflarenet The question is little confusing, do you have `onmousedown` handler on the element? If yes, then you don't need that `.each`.. as you can call `calendar(id)` from the `inline`. However, I don't think it would be undefined, if you pass the value. http://jsfiddle.net/3cc4kqou/